# Proxmox host as NFS server or guest container as NFS server?

Tags: nfs, proxmox

I want to setup a NFS server to make my data accessible between machines. I have one physical machine that has Proxmox installed, I don't have another machine to use as a separate NFS server. Now I'm trying to figure out what is my best option to setup the NFS server.

Note: on the Proxmox host is a volume that needs to be used as data storage volume for the NFS server.

I thought I have two options:

1. Install NFS server directly on the proxmox server and access the
   data from the clients by pointing to the proxmox host. The proxmox
   host manages the shares etc.
2. Install a container node on proxmox, install the nfs-kernel-server
   package on the container node and mount the data storage volume. The
   NFS container node manages the the shares etc.

[image: Note: There are two separate nodes in option #1, Node #1 and Node #2 (forgot to change it.)]

Any advise is appreciated!

Comment: have you take a look into the proxmox forum? https://forum.proxmox.com/threads/accessing-a-host-partition-from-inside-a-container.54560/ I think that will help you and if it solves your issue I would be happy if you would like to accept it as answer

Comment: You can try to run ganesha-nfs sever in  a container